# Surface pro 3 microphone array, how to access them separately?

Tags: c#, audio, windows-10-universal, audio-recording, surface-pro

I have a surface pro 3 and I need to test all of the microphones built in to device(to see if every one of these work). Basically I need to develop an UWP app that can record audio so I can further analyze the record quality and also detect if some of the microphones are broken. I have already developed some parts of an app, but accessing separate microphones is still confusing.

As far as I have searched the Surface pro 3 has 2 microphones: 1 at the front and 1 at the back, but there is no information on how these are configured. Are they connected as 2 stereo mic? are they separate devices that I can also have separate access programmatically? also can I make program that can choose between 3 recording devices (front mic, back mic and input from audio jack) ?

Answer (score 0):

> Are they connected as 2 stereo mic? are they separate devices that I can also have separate access programmatically? also can I make program that can choose between 3 recording devices (front mic, back mic and input from audio jack) ?

You could use the [Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br225393) to get a list of the system's available audio render devices by calling [FindAllAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br225432).

Please check the [Audio Creation](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/AudioCreation/cs/AudioCreation/Scenario2_DeviceCapture.xaml.cs#L168) sample to learn how to use the **Windows.Media.Audio** namespace to create audio graphs for audio routing, mixing, and processing scenarios.